# Is Comodo Firewall and Zonealarm Firewall compatible with avast free 2014?

Tags: firewall

on windows 8.1 currently using avast free antivirus 2014 ,is it possible to use free firewall like comodo or zonealarm with it simultaneously with avast?After installing any will problem occur?

Comment: I would simply use a virtual machine to confirm any compatability problems. Microsoft provides free Windows 8.1 virtual machines for testing purposes.  You can also contact Avast and/or Zonealarm to confirm if any incompatabilies have been reported.

Comment: When installing and configuring Avast just make sure to disable any firewall features that Zone or Comodo will be responsible for. You don't want two applications trying to be a firewall.